# Does the -server flag affect Tomcat behaviour (as opposed to performance)

Tags: tomcat, jvm, jvm-arguments

I know that the `-server` JVM flag causes the JVM to use the Server VM rather than the Client VM, however, according to some internal documentation at my workplace, the presence/absence of this flag causes Tomcat to do/not-do on-the-fly JSP compilation.

Not knowing Tomcat that well, does anyone know if this is the case? My guess is that it is a misunderstanding of the flag on the author's part, but I wanted to be sure.

Thanks in advance

Rich

Comment: JSP on-the-fly compilation *works* with -server and -client modes. I think it's the performance of the JSP compilation in client mode which is more favourable than in server mode. I'm not too sure (hence the comment) maybe this is linked to the -XX:CompileThreshold flag which is 10000 for server and 1500 for client.

Comment: Yeah, I was sure it worked in both scenarios - the comment seemed to disagree, and implied it was explicitly disabled when running in the client mode.

Comment: @JoseK TBH you've answered my question - if you want to put it below, I can then accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the comments,

JSP on-the-fly compilation works with -server and -client modes.

I think it's the performance of the JSP compilation in client mode which is more favourable than in server mode. 
This is most probably linked to the -XX:CompileThreshold flag which is 10000 for server and 1500 for client.

Some related reading is http://java.itags.org/hotspot-virtual-machine/163285/ and [Technique or utility to minimize Java "warm-up" time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481853/technique-or-utility-to-minimize-java-warm-up-time)